# Can I identify rings similar to the way I can identify wands?

Tags: nethack

In NetHack, zapping the floor with a wand can cause some effects to help you identify it (for example, "The bugs on the floor stop moving!" can be a wand of sleep or death.)

Rings are another common item like wands. However, they can not use the same trick as wands to identify them.

I really hate it when I have a ring of aggravate monster when I'm trying to sneak around, especially if it's cursed.

Is there a method I can use to identify rings in a similar fashion as wands?

Comment: Don't try on cursed rings in any event...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rings are one of the trickier (riskier) items in nethack to identify.  Short of using a Scroll of Identify on them or (gasp!) putting it on, you might be interested in dropping them into sinks.

- Pro:  You get a message that helps you figure out what the ring was.
- Con:  You are *very* likely to loose the ring.

Prior to v3.6, it was recommended to have a duplicate that you can `N`ame.  Now you can `N`ame from your `d`iscoveries list, and don't actually need to have the "identified" item on your person.  ... of course you should `N`ame it something like "Test Subject" first to make sure it's *on* your discoveries list.

Less effective and less damaging is to try on a ring that you *know* is uncursed.  Altars & Pets are both good techniques for filtering out Cursed items.  Unfortunately only a small number of rings are readily identifiable by simply wearing them, and many of those will more likely be cursed...

---

Ilmari Karonen's excellent comment added in for posterity:

> Also, when trying on uncursed rings, be prepared for conflict (don't stand next to a powerful pet or peaceful creature), polymorph (be somewhere safe, and don't wear your best armor) and teleportation (be on a safe level -- or better yet, in Sokoban or some other non-teleport level -- and don't test unpaid rings in a shop unless you can handle Kops and an angry shopkeeper).

Answer (score 1):

For any unidentified item, first pet test if possible (pets avoid or move RELUCTANTLY over cursed, otherwise it's  UC/blessed) in absence of an altar. Then go to a General Store or item-specific store and price-check (I always price-check all items in the store as well). Bear in mind a few things though.

1) Charisma affects buying (3-5 X2, 6-7 x1.5, 8-10 X1.33, 11-15 X1, 16-17 X.75, 18 X.67, 19-25 X.5), but not selling price (always half nominal price, exception  see next). Nominal prices can be found in lists on the wiki--I print these lists so they're handy) .

2) Tourists under Levl15 and others wearing a visible t-shirt get charged X1.33 (how this works in conjunction with charisma? I 'm not sure) , and get paid 1/3 instead of 1/2,  nominal price regardless of charisma.

3)  Blessed and cursed items often (but not always) get an unspecified surcharge both buying and selling (I'll post if I remember what it is).

4)When selling, remember to say NO if you want to keep it.  Also, try selling the same item a few times, shopkeepers often try to buy things at a reduced price.  Use the higher price as a rule.

5) Use #name to remember what the nominal price is if you still are.t sure (ex; c100 is "cursed $100," uc100 is "uc/blessed.$100," etc. for pet-tested/price-checked items).  Using the \ key, you can check to see which other same-priced items you've already found to narrow the possibilities.
 Hope this helps, and may Tyr be with you.

Comment: Very useful. I've seen pets move reluctantly but never knew it was due to cursed items.

Comment: If you don't mind spoilers, there's a good price ID tool: http://nethack.roy.org/clippy